# Build the grails application war file using the jenkins is failing

Tags: grails, jenkins

[image]

I have configured the jenkins job for building the grails application war file as shown in the picture. I have checked the output console i got the following error.

```
Output console Error: [JENKINS-7702] sanitizing $JAVA_OPTS
    [workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"G:\practice\jenkins\tools\com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstallation\grails-2.2.4\bin\grails.bat -Dgrails.work.dir=/G:/practice/jenkins/jobs/Grails-Jenkins/workspace//target clean --non-interactive --plain-output && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
    Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:808)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:802)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1008)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:209)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.<clinit>(DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.java:33)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:96)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:73)
        at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:33)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:62)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.<init>(Closure.java:221)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.<init>(Closure.java:238)
        at groovy.lang.Closure$1.<init>(Closure.java:205)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.<clinit>(Closure.java:205)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.<clinit>(GrailsScriptRunner.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
```

Please assist me on the grails build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh dependiences before compile:

```
clean refresh-dependencies "war target/ROOT.war"
```

btw we usually use field `Exec command` and add there custom bash script to control flow and place of generated files.

Updated:
Basing on [this thread](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/logging-failure-with-tomcat-6-0-29-jvm-1-6-0-30-b12-ubuntu-10-04-3-LTS-td4531175.html):

> That looks like your logging.properties file contains invalid
>   settings.

or

> It appears that the JMX agent is using Tomcat's logging.properties but
>   with the unmodified java.util.logging package from the JRE rather than
>   JULI from Tomcat.  Can you show us what the eventual command line is
>   that launches Tomcat?  The parameter specifying
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager looks like it's missing.

Comment: I have tried the above solutions:

**targets**: clean refresh-dependencies "war target/ROOT.war" 

But still getting the same error.

Comment: Getting the below error:
`[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\grails-2.2.4\bin\grails.bat -Dgrails.work.dir=/G:/practice/jenkins/jobs/Grails-Jenkins/workspace//target upgrade --non-interactive && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"`

Comment: do you have `CATALINA_HOME` set?

Comment: I set the environment variable CATELINE_HOME for tomcat server

Still getting the some errors:
1:`Can't load log handler "4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler`

2.`Can't load log handler "3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler`

3.`Can't load log handler "2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler`

Comment: But build getting success and deploying to the tomcat server. I have no idea why i am getting those errors still....

Comment: Check this out: http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/logging-failure-with-tomcat-6-0-29-jvm-1-6-0-30-b12-ubuntu-10-04-3-LTS-td4531175.html